# Angular Material datepicker broken in 1.1.1?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-material

Am I missing something or is Angular Material's datepicker broken in version 1.1.1?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.css">
        <title>foo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main ng-controller="FooController">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
            <div><md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Choose NOW!"></md-datepicker></div>
            <div ng-bind="myDate"></div>
        </main>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                "use strict";
                var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);

                app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.myDate = null;
                }]);
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can save this to a HTML file and open it in your browser, or alternatively here is a live demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbgVeq

If I try to open the datepicker, it just opens a more or less fully blank dialog. But if I change Material version to 1.1.0 (both in JS and CSS), it works fine. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a change in angular 1.6.

> preAssignBindingsEnabled to false by default

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

You use the workaround provided in the changelog:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
  })
```

Until angular material has fixed the issue.